# Scipy.sparse.csr_matrix: How to get top ten values and indices?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large `csr_matrix` and I am interested in the top ten values and their indices each row. But I did not find a decent way to manipulate the matrix.

Here is my current solution and the main idea is to process them row by row:

```
row = csr_matrix.getrow(row_number).toarray()[0].ravel()
top_ten_indicies = row.argsort()[-10:]
top_ten_values = row[row.argsort()[-10:]]
```

By doing this, the advantages of `csr_matrix` is not fully used. It's more like a brute force solution.

Comment: It's hard to suggest a better solution when you don't even give us one.  My guess is that you'll have to either work with the dense version, or work row by row (possibly from the `lil` format).

Comment: @hpaulj Updated the problem, thx

Comment: I found another SO question that asked for the top values for the whole sparse matrix.  One of the answers suggested using `argpartion` as being faster than `argsort`.  But there's still the question of whether you can better than to iterate row by row.  `lil` and `csr` are the 2 fastest formats for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see what the advantages of `csr` format are in this case.  Sure, all the nonzero values are collected in one `.data` array, with the corresponding column indexes in `.indices`.  But they are in blocks of varying length.  And that means they can't be processed in parallel or with `numpy` array strides.

One solution is the pad those blocks into common length blocks.  That's what `.toarray()` does.  Then you can find the maximum values with `argsort(axis=1) or with`argpartition`.

Another is to break them into row sized blocks, and process each of those.  That's what you are doing with the `.getrow`.  Another way of breaking them up is convert to `lil` format, and process the sublists of the `.data` and `.rows` arrays.

A possible third option is to use the `ufunc` `reduceat` method.  This lets you apply `ufunc` `reduction` methods to sequential blocks of an array.  There are established `ufunc` like `np.add` that take advantage of this.  `argsort` is not such a function.  But there is a way of constructing a `ufunc` from a Python function, and gain some modest speed over regular Python iteration.  [I need to look up a recent SO question that illustrates this.]

I'll illustrate some of this with a simpler function, sum over rows.

If `A2` is a csr matrix.

```
A2.sum(axis=1)  # the fastest compile csr method
A2.A.sum(axis=1)  # same, but with a dense intermediary
[np.sum(l.data) for l in A2]  # iterate over the rows of A2
[np.sum(A2.getrow(i).data) for i in range(A2.shape[0])]  # iterate with index
[np.sum(l) for l in A2.tolil().data]  # sum the sublists of lil format
np.add.reduceat(A2.data, A2.indptr[:-1])  # with reduceat
```

`A2.sum(axis=1)` is implemented as a matrix multiplication.  That's not relevant to the sort problem, but still an interesting way of looking at the summation problem.  Remember `csr` format was developed for efficient multiplication.

For a my current sample matrix (created for another SO sparse question)

```
<8x47752 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
     with 32 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

some comparative times are

```
In [694]: timeit np.add.reduceat(A2.data, A2.indptr[:-1])
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.41 µs per loop

In [695]: timeit A2.sum(axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.6 µs per loop

In [696]: timeit [np.sum(l) for l in A2.tolil().data]
1000 loops, best of 3: 280 µs per loop
```

Everything else is 1ms or more.

I suggest focusing on developing your one-row function, something like:

```
def max_n(row_data, row_indices, n):
    i = row_data.argsort()[-n:]
    # i = row_data.argpartition(-n)[-n:]
    top_values = row_data[i]
    top_indices = row_indices[i]  # do the sparse indices matter?
    return top_values, top_indices, i
```

Then see how if fits in one of these iteration methods.  `tolil()` looks most promising.

I haven't addressed the question of how to collect these results.  Should they be lists of lists, array with 10 columns, another sparse matrix with 10 values per row, etc.?

---

[sorting each row of a large sparse & saving top K values & column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297071/sorting-each-row-of-a-large-sparse-saving-top-k-values-column-index) - Similar question from several years back, but unanswered.

[Argmax of each row or column in scipy sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30742572/argmax-of-each-row-or-column-in-scipy-sparse-matrix)  - Recent question seeking `argmax` for rows of `csr`.  I discuss some of the same issues.

[how to speed up loop in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622801/how-to-speed-up-loop-in-numpy/31623674#31623674)  - example of how to use `np.frompyfunc` to create a `ufunc`.  I don't know if the resulting function has the `.reduceat` method.

[Increasing value of top k elements in sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868129/increasing-value-of-top-k-elements-in-sparse-matrix/24868338#24868338)  - get the top k elements of csr (not by row).  Case for `argpartition`.

---

The row summation implemented with `np.frompyfunc`:

```
In [741]: def foo(a,b):
    return a+b  
In [742]: vfoo=np.frompyfunc(foo,2,1)
In [743]: timeit vfoo.reduceat(A2.data,A2.indptr[:-1],dtype=object).astype(float)
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.2 µs per loop
```

That's respectable speed.  But I can't think of a way of writing a binary function (takes to 2 arguments) that would implement `argsort` via reduction.  So this is probably a deadend for this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Just to answer the original question (for people like me who found this question looking for copy-pasta), here's a solution using multiprocessing based on @hpaulj's suggestion of converting to `lil_matrix`, and iterating over rows

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def _top_k(args):
    """
    Helper function to process a single row of top_k
    """
    data, row = args
    data, row = zip(*sorted(zip(data, row), reverse=True)[:k])
    return data, row

def top_k(m, k):
    """
    Keep only the top k elements of each row in a csr_matrix
    """
    ml = m.tolil()
    with Pool() as p:
        ms = p.map(_top_k, zip(ml.data, ml.rows))
    ml.data, ml.rows = zip(*ms)
    return ml.tocsr()
```

Comment: [:k] is undefined

Comment: fwiw _top_k can be improved by using heapq instead of sorting the whole row and then taking the top k values. Even though the matrix is sparse, it could still have some rows with many more entries than k.

Answer (score 5):

One would require to iterate over the rows and get the top indices for each row separately. But this loop can be jited(and parallelized) to get extremely fast function.

```
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def row_topk_csr(data, indices, indptr, K):
    m = indptr.shape[0] - 1
    max_indices = np.zeros((m, K), dtype=indices.dtype)
    max_values = np.zeros((m, K), dtype=data.dtype)

    for i in nb.prange(m):
        top_inds = np.argsort(data[indptr[i] : indptr[i + 1]])[::-1][:K]
        max_indices[i] = indices[indptr[i] : indptr[i + 1]][top_inds]
        max_values[i] = data[indptr[i] : indptr[i + 1]][top_inds]

    return max_indices, max_values
```

Call it like this:

```
top_pred_indices, _ = row_topk_csr(csr_mat.data, csr_mat.indices, csr_mat.indptr, K)
```

I need to frequently perform this operation, and this function is fast enough for me, executes in <1s on 1mil x 400k sparse matrix.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak Saini, unfortunately this doesn't work when K is bigger than nonzero values in a given row (not uncommon for very sparse matrices). Do you have any idea how to work around that? changed the assignment into max_indices and max_values to `
 max_indices[i, :len(top_inds)]`
However, this of course leaves zeros which is also wrong.