# Get top-n items of every row in a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, top-n

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790819/scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-how-to-get-top-ten-values-and-indices) similar question, I still can't fully understand how to go about implementing the solution im looking for.  I have a sparse matrix, i.e.:

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy import sparse
 arr = np.array([[0,5,3,0,2],[6,0,4,9,0],[0,0,0,6,8]])
 arr_csc = sparse.csc_matrix(arr)
```

I would like to **efficiently** get the top n items **of each row**, without converting the sparse matrix to dense.
The end result should look like this (assuming n=2):

```
 top_n_arr = np.array([[0,5,3,0,0],[6,0,0,9,0],[0,0,0,6,8]])
 top_n_arr_csc = sparse.csc_matrix(top_n_arr)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is wrong with the linked answer?  Does it not work in your case?  or you just don't understand it?  Or it isn't **efficient** enough?

I was going to suggest working out a means of finding the top values for a row of an `lil` format matrix, and apply that row by row.  But I would just be repeating my earlier answer.

---

OK, my previous answer was a start, but lacked some details on iterating through the `lol` format.  Here's a start; it probably could be cleaned up.

Make the array, and a `lil` version:

```
In [42]: arr = np.array([[0,5,3,0,2],[6,0,4,9,0],[0,0,0,6,8]])    
In [43]: arr_sp=sparse.csc_matrix(arr)
In [44]: arr_ll=arr_sp.tolil()
```

The row function from the previous answer:

```
def max_n(row_data, row_indices, n):
        i = row_data.argsort()[-n:]
        # i = row_data.argpartition(-n)[-n:]
        top_values = row_data[i]
        top_indices = row_indices[i]  # do the sparse indices matter?
        return top_values, top_indices, i
```

Iterate over the rows of `arr_ll`, apply this function and replace the elements:

```
In [46]: for i in range(arr_ll.shape[0]):
    d,r=max_n(np.array(arr_ll.data[i]),np.array(arr_ll.rows[i]),2)[:2]
    arr_ll.data[i]=d.tolist()
    arr_ll.rows[i]=r.tolist()
   ....:     

In [47]: arr_ll.data
Out[47]: array([[3, 5], [6, 9], [6, 8]], dtype=object)

In [48]: arr_ll.rows
Out[48]: array([[2, 1], [0, 3], [3, 4]], dtype=object)

In [49]: arr_ll.tocsc().A
Out[49]: 
array([[0, 5, 3, 0, 0],
       [6, 0, 0, 9, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 6, 8]])
```

In the `lil` format, the data is stored in 2 object type arrays, as sublists, one with the data numbers, the other with the column indices.

Viewing the data attributes of sparse matrix is handy when doing new things.  Changing those attributes has some risk, since it mess up the whole array.  But it looks like the `lil` format can be tweaked like this safely.

The `csr` format is better for accessing rows than `csc`.  It's data is stored in 3 arrays, `data`, `indices` and `indptr`.  The `lil` format effectively splits 2 of those arrays into sublists based on information in the `indptr`.  `csr` is great for math (multiplication, addition etc), but not so good when changing the sparsity (turning nonzero values into zeros).

Comment: would it be ok to ask you to show how you would do it using lil? I have read your detailed answer but couldn't work it out.