# Finding the top n values in a row of a scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a scipy sparse matrix in CSR format. It's 72665x72665 so it's impractical to convert this matrix to a dense matrix to perform operations on (the dense representation of this matrix is like 40 gigs). The matrix is symmetric, and has about 82 million non-zero entries (~1.5%).

What I would like to be able to do is, for each row, I want to get the indices of the largest N values. If this were a numpy array, I would use `np.argpartition` to do it like so:

```
    for row in matrix:
        top_n_idx = np.argpartition(row,-n)[-n:]
```

Is there something similar to this I can do for a sparse matrix?

Comment: Similar questions from the past: [Get top-n items of every row in a scipy sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135927), and [Scipy.sparse.csr_matrix: How to get top ten values and indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790819)

Answer (score 7):

Improve from @Paul Panzer's solution. Now it can handle the case when any row has less than n values.

```py
def top_n_idx_sparse(matrix, n):
    """Return index of top n values in each row of a sparse matrix."""
    top_n_idx = []
    for le, ri in zip(matrix.indptr[:-1], matrix.indptr[1:]):
        n_row_pick = min(n, ri - le)
        top_n_idx.append(
            matrix.indices[
                le + np.argpartition(matrix.data[le:ri], -n_row_pick)[-n_row_pick:]
            ]
        )
    return top_n_idx
```

**What it does?**

The `matrix.indptr` gives the indices of the beginning of each row stored in the `data` array. So `(lr, ri)` is the range of data indices of non-zero values in each row.
`matrix.data[le:ri]` gives the non-zero values of the row. Passing that to `np.argpartition(..., -n_row_pick)` gives you the local indices that will sort the row for the largest `n_row_pick` elements from the back. `[-n_row_pick:]` select those local indices. Then `le +` shift those local indices back to the indices in the data array. Finally, pass that to `matrix.indices` to get the largest n values indices in the matrix space.

Comment: Can you maybe give a short explanation of what it does i.e why it works?

Comment: So this relates to how CSR format work. You can read http://scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/csr_matrix.html as point out by 
Paul Panzer below. In the question statement, we already know we can find the locations of largest k numbers using `np.argpartition`. Here we simply specify the range of indices in the CSR format.

Answer (score 2):

Directly using the `CSR` format and assuming there are enough positive nonzeros in each row you can write:

```
for le, ri in zip(matrix.indptr[:-1], matrix.indptr[1:]):
    top_n_idx = matrix.indices[le + np.argpartition(matrix.data[le:ri], -n)[-n:]]
```

Comment: Could you explain what this code snippet is doing? And there are many rows that are all 0, so if there is a need for every row to have "enough" nonzeros (what's enough?), I don't think my matrix satisfies that condition.

Comment: @enumaris Well, enough is exactly `n`. If there are fewer than `n` positives then you have to fill up with zeros which is, of course, perfectly doable but tedious because they are not explicitly stored in a `csr` matrix. And, theoretically, there could even be negatives in the top `n` which would lead to even more tedious code. Re what the code is doing, I'll have to ask you to read up on the [`csr` format](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/scipy_sparse/csr_matrix.html) (just the first paragraph) and it should become clear. If not I'll be happy to explain in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

Find top n values:

```
np.sort(matrix[i,:].data)[-n:]
```

Find indices for top n values:

```
matrix[i,:].nonzero()[1][np.argsort(matrix[i,:].data)[-n:]]
```