# Selecting top results from the Sparse csr matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am working on sparse.csr.csr_matrix of size (4860x89462 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'with 9111761 stored elements) and using jupyter notebook 3.7.4

My requirement is to extract the top 2 results based on the Value of the elements in sparse matrix.

I am sharing one example of my sample sparse csr_matrix

Current Sparse matrix

```
  (1, 1)    0.5
  (1, 5)    0.66
  (1, 6)    1.0
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 3)    0.5
  (2, 7)    0.33
```

Desired Sparse matrix

```
  (1, 6)    1.0
  (1, 5)    0.66
  (2, 2)    1.0
  (2, 3)    0.5
```

I am looking for solution which can work on huge matrix without taking much time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the largest N values for each row?  I vaguely recall such a SO in past, though it might have some years ago.  It probably involves iterating on the `A.indptr` to get the values for each row.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207275/finding-the-top-n-values-in-a-row-of-a-scipy-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 0):

```
top_n = 2
out = []

for r in arr:
    if r.data.size <= top_n:
        out.append(r)
    else:
        top_hits = np.argsort(r.data)[-1 * top_n:]
        out.append(sparse.csr_matrix((r.data[top_hits], r.indices[top_hits], np.array([0,len(top_hits)])), shape=(1, arr.shape[1])))
        
out = sparse.vstack(out)
```

This is just not gonna be fast. I don't know of any better way to do it though.