# How to get the top k values by rows in a sparse matrix and mask the remaining values?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given a [sparse.csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) with shape `(M,N)`, how to generate a new sparse matrix with the same shape but with values smaller than the largest `topk` set to zero?

```py
R = sparse.random(5,5, density=0.85, format='csr', random_state=42)
R.toarray()
# array([[0.43194502, 0.78517596, 0.        , 0.59241457, 0.17052412],
#        [0.36636184, 0.        , 0.61185289, 0.52475643, 0.94888554],
#        [0.19967378, 0.30461377, 0.51423444, 0.06505159, 0.45606998],
#        [0.04645041, 0.30424224, 0.29214465, 0.96563203, 0.29122914],
#        [0.60754485, 0.13949386, 0.        , 0.        , 0.80839735]])
```

After finding the `topk` (with k=2) values per row and masking the remaining values, the desired result is:

```py
# array([[0.        , 0.78517596, 0.        , 0.59241457, 0.        ],
#        [0.        , 0.        , 0.61185289, 0.        , 0.94888554],
#        [0.        , 0.30461377, 0.51423444, 0.        , 0.        ],
#        [0.        , 0.30424224, 0.        , 0.96563203, 0.        ],
#        [0.60754485, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.80839735]])
```

**Note**: `M` and `N` is large (`50000`, `700000`).

Comment: I recall some old SO about finding the largest N values per row.  Generally the fastest operations on CSR are matrix-multiplication, and math (such as `sin`) on all nonzero values.  Row sum, for example, can be done with MM.  Other by-row operations may require iteration on the rows via the `indptr` attribute.  That's been discussed in some SO.

Comment: related question found by SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207275/finding-the-top-n-values-in-a-row-of-a-scipy-sparse-matrix

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this in NumPy without much difficulty.

First, find the top kth value in each row.

```
k = 2
kth_largest = np.partition(R, -k, axis=1)[:, -k]
```

Then we can cast `R` to an array (if we haven't already) and compare it to our set of kth largest values.

```
R = R.toarray()
mask = ((R).T < kth_largest).T
```

That mask looks like this:

```
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

We can use it to selectively set some values of the original array to 0. Anywhere that is true is something we want to set to 0.

```
mask = np.ma.masked_where(mask, R)
R[mask.mask] = 0
```