# Multiplying column elements of sparse Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse csc matrix with many zero elements for which I would like to compute the product of all column elements for each row.

i.e.:

```
 A = [[1,2,0,0],
      [2,0,3,0]]
```

should be converted to:

```
V = [[2,
      6]]
```

Using a numpy dense matrix this can be accomplished by replacing all zero values with one values and using `A.prod(1)`. This is however not a option since the dense matrix would be too large.

Is there any way to accomplish this without converting the sparse matrix into a dense one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1:** We can use the row indices of the sparse elements as IDs and perform multiplication of the corresponding values of those elements with [`np.multiply.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) to get the desired output.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

r,c,v = sparse.find(a) # a is input sparse matrix
out = np.zeros(a.shape[0],dtype=a.dtype)
unqr, shift_idx = np.unique(r,return_index=1)
out[unqr] = np.multiply.reduceat(v, shift_idx)
```

Sample run -

```
In [89]: # Let's create a sample csc_matrix
    ...: A = np.array([[-1,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[2,0,3,0],[4,5,6,0],[1,9,0,2]])
    ...: a = csc_matrix(A)
    ...: 

In [90]: a
Out[90]: 
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [91]: a.toarray()
Out[91]: 
array([[-1,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  0],
       [ 1,  9,  0,  2]])

In [92]: out
Out[92]: array([ -2,   0,   6, 120,   0,  18])
```

---

**Approach #2:** We are performing bin-based multiplication. We have bin-based summing solution with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html). So, a trick that could be use here would be converting the numbers to logarithmic numbers, perform bin-based summing and then convert back to original format with `exponential` (reverse of log) and that's it! For negative numbers, we might to add a step or more, but let's see what the implementation be like for non-negative numbers -

```
r,c,v = sparse.find(a)
out = np.exp(np.bincount(r,np.log(v),minlength = a.shape[0]))
out[np.setdiff1d(np.arange(a.shape[0]),r)] = 0
```

A sample run with non-negative numbers -

```
In [118]: a.toarray()
Out[118]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0],
       [1, 9, 0, 2]])

In [120]: out  # Using listed code
Out[120]: array([   2.,    0.,    6.,  120.,   18.])
```

Comment: Use of the `csr` `indptr` in `reduceat` is even faster.

Comment: I checked out both your approaches and found them very helpful. I started using the logarithmic approach which worked great until I had to abandon it because I needed to use `float128` values which `bincount` does not support (yet). I had some trouble with your first approach until I realized that at least on my installation the results of `find` are not sorted by rows but by columns (I used a `csc_matrix` like you did). After figuring it out I was able to solve it using the transposed matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Make a sample:

```
In [51]: A=np.array([[1,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[2,0,3,0]])
In [52]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
```

In `lil` format, values for each row are stored in a list.

```
In [56]: Ml=M.tolil()
In [57]: Ml.data
Out[57]: array([[1, 2], [], [2, 3]], dtype=object)
```

Take the product of each of those:

```
In [58]: np.array([np.prod(i) for i in Ml.data])
Out[58]: array([ 2.,  1.,  6.])
```

In `csr` format values are stored as:

```
In [53]: M.data
Out[53]: array([1, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
In [54]: M.indices
Out[54]: array([0, 1, 0, 2], dtype=int32)
In [55]: M.indptr
Out[55]: array([0, 2, 2, 4], dtype=int32)
```

`indptr` gives the start of the row values. Calculation code on `csr` (and `csc`) matrices routinely perform calculations like this (but compiled):

```
In [94]: lst=[]; i=M.indptr[0]
In [95]: for j in M.indptr[1:]:
    ...:     lst.append(np.product(M.data[i:j]))
    ...:     i = j    
In [96]: lst
Out[96]: [2, 1, 6]
```

With Diavaker's test matrix:

```
In [137]: M.A
Out[137]: 
array([[-1,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  0,  3,  0],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  0],
       [ 1,  9,  0,  2]], dtype=int32)
```

the above loop produces:

```
In [138]: foo(M)
Out[138]: [-2, 1, 6, 120, 18]
```

Divakar's code with `unique` and `reduceat`

```
In [139]: divk(M)
Out[139]: array([ -2,   0,   6, 120,  18], dtype=int32)
```

(different values of the empty row).

Reduceat with `indptr` is simply:

```
In [140]: np.multiply.reduceat(M.data,M.indptr[:-1])
Out[140]: array([ -2,   2,   6, 120,  18], dtype=int32)
```

The value for the empty 2nd line needs to be fixed (with `indptr` values of [2,2,...], `reduceat` uses `M.data[2]`).

```
def wptr(M, empty_val=1):
    res = np.multiply.reduceat(M.data, M.indptr[:-1])
    mask = np.diff(M.indptr)==0
    res[mask] = empty_val
    return res
```

With a larger matrix

```
Mb=sparse.random(1000,1000,.1,format='csr')
```

this `wptr` is about 30x faster than Divaker's version.

More discussion on calculating values across rows of a sparse matrix:
[Scipy.sparse.csr_matrix: How to get top ten values and indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790819/scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-how-to-get-top-ten-values-and-indices)

Comment: Well I don't know much about sparse matrices, but looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prod() method from the numpy module to calculate the product of all elements in each sublist of A while excluding elements of value 0 from being taken into account.

```
import numpy as np
print [[np.prod([x for x in A[i] if x!=0 ]) for i in range(len(A))]]
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don’t just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.