# Most efficient way of accessing non-zero values in row/column in scipy.sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

What is the fastest or, failing that, least wordy way of accessing all non-zero values in a row `row` or column `col` of a `scipy.sparse` matrix `A` in `CSR` format?

Would doing it in another format (say, `COO`) be more efficient?

Right now, I use the following:

```
A[row, A[row, :].nonzero()[1]]
```

or

```
A[A[:, col].nonzero()[0], col]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a problem like this is pays to understand the underlying data structures for the different formats:

```
In [672]: A=sparse.csr_matrix(np.arange(24).reshape(4,6))
In [673]: A.data
Out[673]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], dtype=int32)
In [674]: A.indices
Out[674]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
In [675]: A.indptr
Out[675]: array([ 0,  5, 11, 17, 23], dtype=int32)
```

The `data` values for a row are a slice within `A.data`, but identifying that slice requires some knowledge of the `A.indptr` (see below)

For the `coo`.

```
In [676]: Ac=A.tocoo()
In [677]: Ac.data
Out[677]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], dtype=int32)
In [678]: Ac.row
Out[678]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32)
In [679]: Ac.col
Out[679]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```

Note that `A.nonzeros()` converts to `coo` and returns the `row` and `col` attributes (more or less - look at its code).

For the `lil` format; data is stored by row in lists:

```
In [680]: Al=A.tolil()
In [681]: Al.data
Out[681]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]], dtype=object)
In [682]: Al.rows
Out[682]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=object)
```

===============

Selecting a row of `A` works, though in my experience that tends to be a bit slow, in part because it has to create a new `csr` matrix.  Also your expression seems wordier than needed.

Looking at my first row which has a 0 element (the others are too dense):

```
In [691]: A[0, A[0,:].nonzero()[1]].A
Out[691]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

The whole row, expressed as a dense array is:

```
In [692]: A[0,:].A
Out[692]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)
```

but the `data` attribute of that row is the same as your selection

```
In [693]: A[0,:].data
Out[693]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```

and with the `lil` format

```
In [694]: Al.data[0]
Out[694]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

`A[0,:].tocoo()` doesn't add anything.

Direct access to attributes of a `csr` and `lil` isn't that good when picking columns.  For that `csc` is better, or `lil` of the transpose.

Direct access to the `csr` `data`, with the aid of `indptr`, would be:

```
In [697]: i=0; A.data[A.indptr[i]:A.indptr[i+1]]
Out[697]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int32)
```

Calculations using the `csr` format routinely iterate through `indptr` like this, getting the values of each row - but they do this in compiled code.

A recent related topic, seeking the product of nonzero elements by row:
[Multiplying column elements of sparse Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918414/multiplying-column-elements-of-sparse-matrix)

There I found the `reduceat` using `indptr` was quite fast.

Another tool when dealing with sparse matrices is multiplication

```
In [708]: (sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([1,0,0,0])[None,:])*A)
Out[708]: 
<1x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 5 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`csr` actually does `sum` with this kind of multiplication.  And if my memory is correct, it actually performs `A[0,:]` this way

[Sparse matrix slicing using list of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int)

Comment: I did not know of the `.A` attribute (which simplifies my `np.asarray` and `.toarray()`, `.todense()` mess at other parts of my code). The `.data` attribute indeed does give me what I needed. Thanks for the tips regarding `.indptr` as well!

Comment: My highest voted answer is for an even more obscure property, `M.A1` which turns a `matrix` into a 1d array, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337301/numpy-matrix-to-array/20765358#20765358