# Fast column access over large scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, cython

I am working with scipy's `csc` sparse matrix and currently a major bottleneck in the code is a line similar to the following

```
for i in range(multiply_cols.shape[0]):
   F = F - factor*values[i]*mat.getcol(multiply_cols[i])
```

The matrices that I am working with are extremely large, of size typically more than `10**6x10**6` and I don't want to convert them to dense matrix. In fact I have a restriction to always have the matrix in `csc` format. My attempts show that converting to `coo_matrix` or `lil_matrix` also does not pay off.

Here is my rudimentary attempts using `csc`, `csr` and `coo`:

```
n=1000
sA = csc_matrix(np.random.rand(n,n))
F = np.random.rand(n,1)
multiply_cols = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,int(0.6*n),size=n))
values = np.random.rand(multiply_cols.shape[0])

def foo1(mat,F,values,multiply_cols):
    factor = 0.75
    for i in range(multiply_cols.shape[0]):
        F = F - factor*values[i]*mat.getcol(multiply_cols[i])

def foo2(mat,F,values,multiply_cols):
    factor = 0.75
    mat = mat.tocsr()
    for i in range(multiply_cols.shape[0]):
        F = F - factor*values[i]*mat.getcol(multiply_cols[i])

def foo3(mat,F,values,multiply_cols):
    factor = 0.75
    mat = mat.tocoo()
    for i in range(multiply_cols.shape[0]):
        F = F - factor*values[i]*mat.getcol(multiply_cols[i])

def foo4(mat,F,values,multiply_cols):
    factor = 0.75
    mat = mat.tolil()
    for i in range(multiply_cols.shape[0]):
        F = F - factor*values[i]*mat.getcol(multiply_cols[i])
```

and timing them I get:

```
In [41]: %timeit foo1(sA,F,values,multiply_cols)
10 loops, best of 3: 133 ms per loop

In [42]: %timeit foo2(sA,F,values,multiply_cols)
1 loop, best of 3: 999 ms per loop

In [43]: %timeit foo3(sA,F,values,multiply_cols)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.38 s per loop

In [44]: %timeit foo4(sA,F,values,multiply_cols)
1 loop, best of 3: 45.1 s per loop
```

So certainly `coo_matrix` and `lil_matrix` are not a good choice here. Does anyone know a faster way of doing this. Is it a good option to retrieve the underlyng `indptr`, `indices` and `data` have a custom `cython` solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40984887/901925 - discussion of row access with `csr`. And http://stackoverflow.com/a/39500986/901925

Comment: @TasamFarkie I don't know how good your benchmark is. Its seems likely that an efficient implementation involves not doing work on empty cells, but your test matrix is entirely filled

Comment: So, is `sA` the input sparse matix? If so, I don't see it being used later on in the code.

Comment: In the `%timeit` lines it's passed to `foo*`

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. Thanks @DavidW.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in

[Sparse matrix slicing using list of int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500649/sparse-matrix-slicing-using-list-of-int/39500986#39500986)

that column (or row) indexing for `sparse` matrices is essentially a matrix multiplication task - construct a sparse matrix with the right mix of 1s and 0s, and multiply.  Also row (and column) sums are done with multiplication.

This function implements that idea.  `M` is a 1 column sparse matrix, with `values` in the `multiply_cols` slots:

```
def wghtsum(sA, values, multiply_cols):
   cols = np.zeros_like(multiply_cols)
   M=sparse.csc_matrix((values,(multiply_cols,cols)),shape=(sA.shape[1],1))
   return (sA*M).A
```

testing:

```
In [794]: F1=wghtsum(sA,values,multiply_cols)
In [800]: F2=(sA[:,multiply_cols]*values)[:,None]  # Divaker's
In [802]: np.allclose(F1,F2)
Out[802]: True
```

It has a modest time savings over `@Divakar's` solution:

```
In [803]: timeit F2=(sA[:,multiply_cols]*values)[:,None]
100 loops, best of 3: 18.3 ms per loop
In [804]: timeit F1=wghtsum(sA,values,multiply_cols)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.57 ms per loop
```

=======

`sA` as created is dense - it's a sparse rendition of a dense random array.  `sparse.rand` can be used to create a sparse random matrix with a defined level of sparsity.

In testing your `foo1` I had a problem with `getcol`:

```
In [818]: sA.getcol(multiply_cols[0])
...
TypeError: an integer is required
In [819]: sA.getcol(multiply_cols[0].item())
Out[819]: 
<1000x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [822]: sA[:,multiply_cols[0]]
Out[822]: 
<1000x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
```

I suspect that's caused by a `scipy` version difference.

```
In [821]: scipy.__version__
Out[821]: '0.17.0'
```

This issue did go away in 0.18; but I can't find a relevant issue/pullrequest.

Comment: This is very informative. Thanks mate! For the actual sparse matrices that I have, this approach performs considerably faster than Divakar's solution. However I have that noticed for certain sparsity patterns this approach gives erroneous results. I'm trying to investigate this and perhaps come up with MWE.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use a vectorized approach that uses matrix-multiplication of sliced out columns from sparse matrix  against `values`, like so -

```
F -= (mat[:,multiply_cols]*values*factor)[:,None]
```

**Benchmarking**

It seems `foo1` is the fastest of the lot listed in the question. So, let's time the proposed approach against that one.

Function definitions -

```
def foo1(mat,F,values,multiply_cols):
    factor = 0.75
    outF = F.copy()
    for i in range(multiply_cols.shape[0]):
        outF -= factor*values[i]*mat.getcol(multiply_cols[i])
    return outF

def foo_vectorized(mat,F,values,multiply_cols):
    factor = 0.75 
    return F - (mat[:,multiply_cols]*values*factor)[:,None]
```

Timings and verification on bigger set with sparseness -

```
In [242]: # Setup inputs
     ...: n = 3000
     ...: mat = csc_matrix(np.random.randint(0,3,(n,n))) #Sparseness with  0s
     ...: F = np.random.rand(n,1)
     ...: multiply_cols = np.unique(np.random.randint(0,int(0.6*n),size=n))
     ...: values = np.random.rand(multiply_cols.shape[0])
     ...: 

In [243]: out1 = foo1(mat,F,values,multiply_cols)

In [244]: out2 = foo_vectorized(mat,F,values,multiply_cols)

In [245]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[245]: True

In [246]: %timeit foo1(mat,F,values,multiply_cols)
1 loops, best of 3: 641 ms per loop

In [247]: %timeit foo_vectorized(mat,F,values,multiply_cols)
10 loops, best of 3: 40.3 ms per loop

In [248]: 641/40.3
Out[248]: 15.905707196029779
```

There we have a **`15x+`** speedup!